# Pandas: Apply filter on a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ["blue","blue","blue", "blue","green"], 'val1': [5, 3, 2, 2, 5], 'val2':[1, 3, 2, 2, 5]})
print(df)

  category  val1  val2
0     blue     5     1
1     blue     3     3
2     blue     2     2
3     blue     2     2
4    green     5     5
```

I want to get the rows where any value is > 3. For my example here that has only two columns I can just do

```
df.loc[(df['val1'] > 3) | (df['val2'] > 3)]

    category    val1    val2
0   blue    5   1
4   green   5   5
```

Now let's say I have a dataset with a large amount of (numeric) columns, and I want to get all rows where the value of any of the numeric columns meets a condition (like for example being > 3). Is there a way to check a condition over multiple columns without having to chain them with `|` ?

So for example let's say I have a dataframe with n columns named val1 to valn and I want all rows where any of the values in val1 to valn is > 3. Is there a better way / shorter way of doing it than

```
df.loc[(df['val1'] > 3) | (df['val2'] > 3) | ... | (df['valn'] > 3)]
```

?

Comment: `df.loc[df.gt(3).any(1)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use df.any() as below. This will work for any number of columns (we ignore the first column 'category' as it's no numeric):

```
res=df[(df.iloc[:,1:] >3).any(axis=1)]
```

Result for your current dataframe is:

```
>>>print(res)

  category  val1  val2
0     blue     5     1
4    green     5     5
```

Comment: Consider this `df.loc[df.filter(like='val').gt(3).any(1)]`, this would filter all columns with `val` and check for greater than 3.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. A further question on this, how would I add additonal conditions to that? Say for example I want to filter for all rows that contain a value that is both >3 but also <6 ?

Comment: Try this: `res=df[((df.iloc[:,1:] >3) & (df.iloc[:,1:] <6)).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 3):

Use just selected columns for the test

```
checkColumns = ['val1','val2','val3','val25']
dfSub = df.loc[df[checkColumns].gt(3).any(1)]
```